# Why can't I run my lua script?

Tags: scripting, lua

Okay, so I'm trying to learn Lua. I am getting this error:

```
'=' expected near '<eof>'
```

Using this line to run it.

```
dofile(”.\\test.lua”)
```

And my script is just `print("Hello World!")`

How do I run this?

Comment: Is your `dofile(”.\\test.lua”)` script really using [typographic quotation marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark)? Or is that just an artifact of some mechanism you used to post here? I have a feeling Lua is only going to use standard _dumb_ quotation marks: `"`.

Comment: Nah, it's only using normal ones.

Comment: What do you get if you type in Print("Hello World")?

Comment: What is the output of **f=assert(loadfile(".\\test.lua")) f()** ?

Comment: Try running `luac -p test.lua` and paste here what it says

Comment: luac5.1: test.lua:3: '=' expected near '<eof>'

Comment: What is the third line of test.lua?

Answer (score 2):

Guess I installed the wrong thing. I downloaded this and now everything works. Thank you all for your help. ^_^
http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/downloads/detail?name=LuaForWindows_v5.1.4-40.exe&can=2&q=